# Remove duplicate array from response comparing attribute value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to remove a duplicate array from the response on the basis of the attribute value. If the `attribute_value` data match with other array attribute value then other should be removed.

The logic is very simple. check duplicate attribute_value in each array and remove duplicate array and return
In response. now you can see the attribute value = 1 is thrice
and attribute value = 2 is twice

How do i compare and remove whole array if I see attribute value duplicate?

I tried with filter method which seems not working. Please help.

```
for(var j=0; j<social_post_link.length; j++){
    newFilterarray = social_post_link[j].activity_attributes[0].attribute_value.filter(function(item, index) {
      if (social_post_link[j].activity_attributes[0].attribute_value.indexOf(item) == index){
        return social_post_link;
      }
    });                                             
}
```

Response

```
[
  {
    "id": "484822",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868117",
        "activity_id": "484822",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484884",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868175",
        "activity_id": "484884",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484888",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868182",
        "activity_id": "484888",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484823",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868120",
        "activity_id": "484823",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484975",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868344",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484891",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868189",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "3",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484903",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868200",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "4",
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Desired output

```
    [
  {
    "id": "484822",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868117",
        "activity_id": "484822",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484823",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868120",
        "activity_id": "484823",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484891",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868189",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "3",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484903",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868200",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "4",
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You are using the function `filter` on a string. That throws an error there.

Comment: yes true. I was just trying to show my code. and desire output. Can you help me to correct the code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the lodash utility [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy),

where `iteratee` is a function that returns the value you want to compare against.

In your case, it would probably look like the following:

```
const uniqueLinks = _.uniqBy(social_post_link, item =>
  item.activity_attributes[0].attribute_value
)
```

### Edit:

Here is a vanilla JS function that will accomplish the same.

```js
const filterByIteratee = (array, iteratee) => {

  // Empty object to store attributes as we encounter them
  const previousAttributeNames = {

  }

  return array.filter(item => {
    // Get the right value
    const itemValue = iteratee(item)

    // Check if we have already stored this item
    if (previousAttributeNames.hasOwnProperty(itemValue)) return false
    else {
      // Store the item so next time we encounter it we filter it out
      previousAttributeNames[itemValue] = true
      return true  
    }
  })
}
```

It will loop through an array, store its identifier by some function, and return only the first instance of each item.

Use it the same way:

```
const uniqueLinks = filterByIteratee(social_post_link, item =>
  item.activity_attributes[0].attribute_value
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This seems good but would like to prefer without other third party js. I am using jquery. Any suggestion

Comment: @Santosh I've edited my original comment with a solution for you

Comment: This answer is nice, but it doesnt take into consideration that activity_attributes is an array, and it can have more than one element!

Comment: Hi @Santosh, this is probably because of the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax. I've uploaded a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/nickells/dea6ca8d58d64af571a6692da0bb0c71) with the "old school" version.

Comment: If you find yourself caring about IE11 compatibility, you might want to look into adding Babel as a build step. That way you can write modern JavaScript and it will all get transpiled before shipping to your users.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will surely try babel. Although your old schools code is working awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably **not** the best performing solution. but it works for your requirements.

```
var resultArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < social_post_link.length; i++) {
  var currentSocialLink = social_post_link[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < currentSocialLink.activity_attributes.length; j++) {
    if (!resultArray.some(val => 
       val.activity_attributes.some(activity => 
       activity.attribute_value === currentSocialLink.activity_attributes[j].attribute_value))) {

       resultArray.push(currentSocialLink);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working on IE11. It seems like arrow function is not working.

Answer (score -1):

```
function removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) { // removes duplicate objects from array
    return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
        return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
    });
};
```

I found this function not too long ago which removes duplicate objects from an array. Pass it the array and the property you wish to not be duplicated.

Comment: This wont work for his case. His `prop` is nested in an array of objects.

Comment: Oh true, I'll keep it up for future reference.